# Detail documentation to implement Role based access control in yii from initial?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

I am a newbie in yii Framework and i go through various documentation for Role based access control in yii like simple rbac ,rights extension ,user extension ,rbam.

I am confused how to implement the role based access control in yii  and what is based ?

My requirement is to manage three types of roles only?
Where to learn how the filter function work ?
Actually Where i will find the detail documentation for roles ?

Answer (score 0):

An answers to nearly all of your questions you can find in [Role-Based Access Control](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#role-based-access-control) guide.